# Laravel 6 Dropdown Search Filter

Tags: php, laravel

[table column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVE59.png)

[blade image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U2sG.png)

I'm making a search filter in laravel 6. I have to search using email, vendorname, status, startdate, and enddate. Search by email is working but when I search using vendorname it's not working it fetch all leads. Please help me

**controller code**

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('is_admin', Null)->get();

    $customer_email = $request->input('customer_email');
    $vendor_name = $request->input('vendor_name');

    

    $leads = DB::table('leads')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'leads.vendor_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('leads.*', 'users.name')
            ->where ( 'customer_email', 'LIKE', '%' . $customer_email . '%' )
            ->orWhere ( 'vendor_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $vendor_name . '%' )
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();

    //return $leads;

    return view('admin.view-leads', compact('leads'), compact('users'));

    
}
```

**my blade file**

```
        <form action="{{url('admin/search')}}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row input-daterange">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="customer_email" id="customer_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <select class="form-control" name="vendor_name" id="vendor_name">
                            <option>Select Vendor Name</option>
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Status" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="submit" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                        <button type="button" name="refresh" id="refresh" class="btn btn-default">Refresh</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: please print the query being fired with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ->orWhere ( 'vendor_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $vendor_name . '%' )
```

Instead of "vendor_id", shouldn't it be the Vendor Name Column?

Comment: sir, no because vendorname is dynamic in select dropdown. please explain your answer

Comment: Can you post your Table Column Names?

Answer (score 0):

If vendor_id is integer i.e user_id is key then don't use `LIKE`. Please try below code once.

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('is_admin', Null)->get();

    $customer_email = $request->input('customer_email');
    $vendor_id = $request->input('vendor_name');
    

    $leads = DB::table('leads')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'leads.vendor_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('leads.*', 'users.name')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($customer_email,$vendor_id) {
                    $query->where('customer_email', 'like', '%' . $customer_email . '%')
                        ->orWhere('vendor_id', $vendor_id)
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    //return $leads;

    return view('admin.view-leads', compact('leads'), compact('users'));

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it still not working...same problem